# Git Branch Management - Pulling reverted commits

Tags: git

I had a branch, `branch-1` that contained changes in 36 files

`branch-1` was merged to `master`

there was a bug, so we reverted.

We realized the bug was a typo, so I'd like to create a new branch, `branch-2` pull all the existing work, fix the typo, and then push to that new branch so I can create a PR in github.

What I've tried:

I have `branch-1` locally, so I checked it out, then tried to `git checkout -b branch-2` but that only copies off of `master`. I figured I'd create a new branch from that old one, fix the typo, pull in master to get all the changes since then, and then push so I could create a PR but that isn't working.

Comment: that article, and it's publisher, doesn't say "you shouldn't use it," he says use the right tool for the job. we have versioned software. the question applies whether it's gitflow or github flow since branching and history applies to both

Comment: He (and well, everyone who's doing Continuous Integration) says that GitFlow doesn't have a lot of use cases. So basically.. you'll have to use it only if you're unlucky and have to support multiple versions of the software _at the same time_, so that different clients could use different versions (and so when found a bug in 2 versions you issue 2 patches and release _both_ v1.0.1 and v2.0.1).

Comment: GitHub flow is _completely_ different from GitFlow and is used in completely different use cases. GitHub flow is a more modern approach because most products these days support only one (latest) version. See https://githubflow.github.io/. Some products still need parallel version histories supported (hence may use the convoluted GitFlow), but that's a rare use case these days.

Comment: saying it's completely different is subjective. It looks like what you are looking for is an industry-wide intervention in naming. Your original comment seems conversational, and to end the conversation I've updated the title to git branch management

Comment: Ok. It's just most people are confused and don't understand branching strategies, and they end up using the wrong ones in wrong situations because of some flashy articles on the internet. A lot of problems wouldn't arise if they were using the right tools that fit their use cases. I'm only trying to educate the crowd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lest assume history:

```
X--X---X---X--M---RM---X   <--- master
 \           /
  \         /
   F---F---F    <--- feature
```

Where

- `M` - merge of feature
- `RM` - reveres of that merge
- `F` - feature branch commits
- `X` - other commits

Now if you like continue feature branch:

```
X--X---X---X--M---RM---X---M2   <--- master
 \           /            /
  \         /            /
   F---F---F -----TypoFix   <--- feature
```

Second attempt of merge `M2` will fail since `RM` is counter acting not only `M` commit but also `F` commits.

In such cases if you like avoid rewriting history (like rebate of feature branch), I prefer create helper branch which contains revert of revert. Leading to history like that:

```
X----X----X----X----M---RM---X---   <--- master
 \                 /     \
  \               /       \
   \             /        RRM <-- helper branch
    \           /           \
     \         /             \
      F---F---F---TypoFix---MRRM   <--- feature
```

This `RRM` commit reverts the `RM` and lets keep old history intact in form which will not interact with `RM` commit in `master` branch.

After that merge `feature` branch into a master will not be a problem.

Other way is to cherry pick `F` commits on top of latest `master` (this is covered by alternative answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that simple.... you need to work on *new* commits built from the old branch so that git *thinks* that those commits have not been merged ever.... it could be done like this... suppose that `branch-1` has 2 straight commits when it was merged in `master`. So... do this:

```
git checkout -b branch-2 branch-1~2
git cherry-pick HEAD..branch-1 # reapply the same commits from branch-1
# they will be _new_ commits, not related to the ones that are already merged
# fix the typo and create a new commit (or rebase and fix the typo, whatever you think is the right way to handle)
```

When you have your branch with the fix already committed, this branch can be merged into `master` and git won't complain about the previous commits already merged.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. `branch-1` had 2 straight commits. When I run the first command, `git checkout branch-2 branch-1~2` I get 
`error: pathspec 'branch-1~2' did not match any file(s) known to git`

Comment: Right.... let me correct the recipe... a little option was skipped. Edited to 2 commits, just in case.